# Javascript - match word by regex - Non-English

Tags: javascript

Need to match words by checking comma between values. Below script works fine for English text as expected.

```js
var str = "Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland";
var res = str.match(/\w.*?\w(?=,\w|$)/g);
console.log(res)
```

But, it doesnt work for non-english characters.. similar logic i need to bring non-english texts as well.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are positive that:

1. you do not use spaces between items after commas
2. space after comma is in the same item
3. '>' is not used in data

You can try without regex:

```
replaceAll = (what, withWhat, str) => {
    const reg = new RegExp(what, 'g');
    return str.replace(reg, withWhat);
}
var str = "Complimentary daily, buffet breakfast,Special amenities, wine and chocolates,two persons at selected hotels ,Food and beverage";
var res = replaceAll(", ",">", str).split(",").map(i=> replaceAll(">", ", ", i))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi johnpan thanks for your code.. Please check in question i implemented your code "Logic implemented as per @johnpan code".   Not sure why  "wine and chocolate" coming to next? It have to be like "Special amenities, wine and chocolates"

Comment: @TDG  code is now updated. Please note that there is an extra space in the item 'two persons at selected hotels ' Is this a valid case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using character matching

```
var res = str.match(/[毎日2名様までの,ボトルワインやチ2名様までご滞在中の,またはラウアメニテ]+/g);
```

or using character ranges, like

```
var res = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ascii code range and base your regex on it

```js
console.log("毎".charCodeAt())
console.log("A".charCodeAt())
console.log("Z".charCodeAt())

console.log("--------");

const s = "毎日2名様までの,ボトルワインやチ, (2名様まで）,ご滞在中の,またはラウ,アメニテ";

[...s].map(l => {
  console.log(l.charCodeAt())
})
```

Comment: Hi.. all my values in array will be dynamic contents.. sorry, thats the reason i cant able to add hardcoded values to check. Thanks